# Ubuntu 22.04 Server (ARM64) not connecting to SSH after a power outage from my Win 10 laptop. "Connection Timed Out" error

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, windows

this is my first post but that’s not important ATM.

I have a Plex Server running on a brand-new Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04 Server LTS.  A storm knocked out power for a second 2 days after installation and setup.  The Pi is powered via a surge protector, so that shouldn't be the issue, but you all have more experience than my 3 days with Linux I assume so correct me if need be.  The machine I am using to SSH into my server is running Win10, and I was using my server prior to the storm hitting today, as well as using SSH to install ease-of-use programs like KeePassXC, these apps are not the issue, I only mention this to express the issue that this has only happened since the power outage.

## Things I have tried:

- Reboot internet router
- Reboot Pi (via HDMI and m&k)
- Reboot Pi (via USB-C power cord)
- Reboot Win10 PC
- Firewall disable (on Pi, have tried to SSH while disabled, still error)
- Firewall enable (on Pi)
- Firewall allow 22 (on Pi) (I have checked the status, claims to be running)
- IP reservation turned off and on for both devices
- Some other things I am probably forgetting, been on this for 2 hours now

## Issue:

- When using ssh user@[Pi IP] I get
  `ssh: connect to host [Pi IP] port 22: Connection timed out`
- Same issue when using the hostname
- RDC will not let me see the remote desktop
- Pinging the Pi returns
  `Reply from [Win 10 IP]: Destination host unreachable.` W/ 4 packets sent and received.

## Final comments

I have tried almost every YouTube video/tutorial I can find, but none of them yield results. The goal is to be able to use my Pi headless and access it from my PC to update and manage it, and that worked for a few days, but this storm has ruined my hard work it seems. I'm to the point of just restarting the Pi OS all over, as much of a pain as it was to do the first time. Please help with any advice you have, I'm all ears.

Comment: If the pi was getting IP address from DHCP, the address probably changed when it rebooted.

Comment: First, good troubleshooting. Second, please connect to the pi locally and run the following commands:
1. ip a 
That will show you the current IP address - check for the one on the same subnet as your PC. It may have changed.
2. ss -tulpn 
That will tell you whether the box is listening on port 22. If it's not, it won't get an SSH connection.
3. sudo systemctl status ssh
That will tell you if SSH is running and operational.

Comment: 1. IP for Pi - 192.168.1.128, laptop is 192.168.1.45     2. tcp state: LISTEN on port 0.0.0.0:22 and [::]:22     3. ssh is active (running) and GREEN color     4. pings still do not work nor does ssh.  please help, idk what to do :(

Comment: What firewall are you using and can your Pi ping your router?

Comment: Ping 192.168.1.1 => from 192...128 Destination Host Unreachable.  Idk about firewall, but I see a lot of ufw and iptables support stuff when I was troubleshooting. My laptop uses windows firewall.

Comment: Have you tried pinging anything **from** the pi? e.g. can both the pi and your Windows machine ping the router

Comment: @IsaacHewitt if your Pi cannot communicate with your router, its networking functionality won't work and you won't be able to SSH to it. Double check that you can ping the router from your Windows machine and if so, perhaps try removing and re-adding the network on your Pi. Disable any firewalls you have added.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, and when I do it does not stop trying to ping, it just goes forever trying to ping, am I supposed to stop it, if so how?

Comment: stop it using `ctrl-c`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have used this before and never thought of it for this, ty so much.  I'm very new obviously